# using / to indicate root directory

Tags: html, internet-explorer, relative-path

This is probably a stupid question, but its hard to search for effectively. I am have defined the following:

```
<img src='/images/image_name.ico' />
```

This properly creates the path to the root directory then the images directory in all of the browsers I have tested, including IE10, but IE9 will not get the path right. Is there a known problem with using / to indicate the site root with IE 9? I just get a broken image even though the file exists at that path.

Comment: The server decides this, not the browser. Take your full URL (http://...) plus this file path, and put it in the address bar. It should be the same for every client, regardless.

Comment: @Diodeus — No. Relative URIs have to be resolved by the browser.

Comment: Paths starting with a slash are not relative.

Comment: @Diodeus — Anything that doesn't start with the scheme is relative. It's just a question about what they are relative to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There are no known issues with IE's ability to resolve root relative URIs.

The usual debug steps you should take are: Check your server logs and browser debug tools to see what is actually being requested, if the request was successful, and if the correct content-type is being specified. Make sure the image file is OK. Check the browser can resolve the URL and open the image directly (without going through a webpage).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an instance of IE9, and since this is an intranet application, I can't use external browser emulators. I will have to wait for QA, but the file is definitely there (it is working in Chrome, FF, and IE10)

Comment: Tell your manager that you need sufficient rights, RAM, CPU and disk space to install and run [a VM with IE9 on it](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads). Expecting you to debug problems where you have to ask *another department* to run a test with every tweak you make is not a reasonable way to work.

Comment: I think the problem has to do with the fact that they are .ico files and IE doesn't like them. I will try using a different image and see if that helps

Comment: sorry about that, it was just an example. I thought the problem was with the path, but apparently its the file extension.